# Express.js route modules not working

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am getting some odd behavior with my exported routes using Express.js. My HTML routes work fine, but my api routes (api routes are in a separate file) return "Cannot GET /api". However if I move my api routes into the same file as my html routes, the api routes suddenly works. I looked at other examples on Stack but none were exported routes to the server file. I want to get both HTML and API routes working while being in separate files. Here's the code:

File Structure:

```
    ├── app
│   ├── data
│   │   └── dogs.js
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── add.html
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── main.css
│   │   ├── home.html
│   │   ├── javascript
│   │   │   └── app.js
│   │   └── survey.html
│   └── routing
│       ├── api-routes.js
│       └── html-routes.js
└── server.js
```

Server.js File

```
// Dependencies
// =============================================================
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var PORT = 8080;
var app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json({type:'application/vnd.api+json'}));


//html routes
app.use('/', require('./app/routing/html-routes'));
app.use('/add', require('./app/routing/html-routes'));
app.use('/survey', require('./app/routing/html-routes'));

//api routes
app.use('/api/:dogs?', require('./app/routing/api-routes'));


// Starts the server to begin listening
// =============================================================
app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log('App listening on PORT ' + PORT);
})
```

html-routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var dogs = require('../data/dogs');

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/home.html'));
})

router.get('/survey', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/survey.html'));
})

router.get('/add', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/add.html'));
})

module.exports = router
```

api-routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var apiRouter = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var dogs = require('../data/dogs');

apiRouter.get('/api/:dogs?', function(req, res){

// refactor this
    var chosen = req.params.dogs;

    if(chosen){
        console.log(chosen);

        for (var i=0; i < dogs.length; i++){

            if (chosen == dogs[i].id){
                res.json(dogs[i]);
                return;
            }
        }

        res.json(false);
    }

    else{
        res.json(dogs);
    }
})

module.exports = apiRouter
```

html routes with api routes in the html-routes.js file. This works and no need to change anything in the server.js file.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var router = express.Router();
    var path = require('path');
    var dogs = require('../data/dogs');



    router.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/home.html'));
    })

    router.get('/survey', function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/survey.html'));
    })

    router.get('/add', function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/add.html'));
    })

    // api routes


    router.get('/api/:dogs?', function(req, res){
    // refactor this
        var chosen = req.params.dogs;

        if(chosen){
            console.log(chosen);

            for (var i=0; i < dogs.length; i++){

                if (chosen == dogs[i].id){
                    res.json(dogs[i]);
                    return;
                }
            }

            res.json(false);
        }

        else{
            res.json(dogs);
        }
    })

    router.post('/api/newdog', function(req, res){

            var newDog = req.body;

            console.log(newDog);

            dogs.push(newDog);

            res.json(newDog);

})


module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server.js file you don't need the `app.use`s you have under //html and //api routes. You can delete those and then just put

```
require("./app/routing/api-routes")(app);
require("./app/routing/html-routes")(app);
```

Now inside your html-routes file turn you don't need to use your `router var = express.Router()`. All you need to do is create a function

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get("/survey", function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/survey.html"));
  })

  app.use(function (req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/home.html"));
  })
}
```

Follow that same style using your api-routes

Comment: Your solution worked @wkerman. Thanks! The api routes refactored looks like this `module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get("/api/:dog?", function(req,res) {
    console.log('end point reached')

    // refactor this
     var chosen = req.params.dogs;

     if(chosen){
      console.log(chosen);

      for (var i=0; i < dogs.length; i++){

       if (chosen == dogs[i].id){
        res.json(dogs[i]);
        return;
       }
      }

      res.json(false);
     }

     else{
      res.json(dogs);
     }
    })
  }`

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues.

First is the order in which you are mounting the routers. You should mount more specific routers first:

```
// more specific
app.use('/api/:dogs?', require('./app/routing/api-routes'));
// less specific
app.use('/', require('./app/routing/html-routes'));
```

(your declarations for `/add` and `/survey` are superfluous, since they will be handled by the latter)

Secondly, routers work relative to their mount path. In other words, if you want a router to handle all routes that start with `/api`, you use this:

```
app.use('/api', router);
```

If you want that same router to handle `/api/foo`, then you should have it handle the route *relative* to the `/api` prefix, like so:

```
router.get('/foo', ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

try with only these 2 lines in server.js

```
//html routes
app.use('/', require('./app/routing/html-routes'));

//api routes
app.use('/api', require('./app/routing/api-routes'));
```

Comment: I get I only need the two route paths now, but it didn't seem to have any effect on my routing and I still receive Cannot GET /api/

Answer (score 0):

Under `app.js/server.js` file make sure you require your new route file at the top. Then on `app.use` do the following:

```
app.use('/', your_new_route);
```

From there you'll be able to call any endpoints defined in your new route e.g

```
router.get('/filesize', function(req, res) {
    console.log('File Uplaod');
    res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null});
});
```